# View Windows Server 2008 password

Tags: windows, passwords, windows-server-2008

I reinstalled my PC and lost the credentials to a remote server. The remote username and password that I have don't work anymore.

What I have is a recovery console via VNC where I can login into a minimalistic XP and view the share where the Windows Server 2008 Web Edition is installed, but just view the files I can not ... actually login into the 2008 R2 web edition OS.

How can I *VIEW* or *CHANGE* the user name password so I can login via remote desktop?

I do have the WHOLE `c:\Users` directory from my previous install — if there is a way to view the stored user/password for this server (because the credentials where saved in the remote desktop) I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

You will need console access (i.e. be ON the physical server) to reset the password, if you don't have any other passwords available. Is this server connected to an AD server? If so reset the password on the domain controller. If it is only using local usernames and passwords, try something such as the UBCD4Win CD to reset the password.

The way that passwords are stored for users of a Windows system, you can not "recover" or "view" the password in clear text, only hashed form. Because of the vast possibilities that could create that password, you're better off clearing the password, and setting a new one

Answer (score 0):

Try using `net user password` command detailed here;

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251394

This may allow you to at least change the password from the command prompt

Comment: I *can not* execute commands on the server because I can not login into it.